# Unable to remove a user from item permision RoleAssignments does not contain RemoveById

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom

I have the following code inside my remote event receiver, where i am trying to remove a user from a list item which have unique permission:-

```
User oUser = context.Site.RootWeb.EnsureUser(linemanagerUser.LookupValue);
context.Load(oUser);
context.ExecuteQuery();
currentItem.RoleAssignments.RemoveById(oUser.Id);
```

but seems RoleAssignments does not contain RemoveById as in the server-side object module.. so can anyone advice on this please?

Error i got on my above code:-

```
'RoleAssignmentCollection' does not contain a definition for 'RemoveById' and no accessible extension method 'RemoveById' accepting a first argument of type 'RoleAssignmentCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below code :

```
currentItem.RoleAssignments.GetByUser(oUser.Id). DeleteObject ()
```

Or

```
   currentItem.RoleAssignments.GetByPrincipal(oUser.Id). DeleteObject ()
```

For details example, you may refer to the below article :

[Remove permission in Sharepoint List using Client Object Model](https://www.google.com/amp/s/rambabualaparthi.wordpress.com/2013/12/30/remove-permission-in-sharepoint-list-using-client-object-model/amp/)